# Force driver to update to new page in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to navigate through Coursera's site using Selenium and I'm having some trouble getting the driver to recognize that the page has changed after logging in. Here is the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.coursera.org/?authMode=login")

# Target the user name input field
try:
    user = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".c-user-modal-controls > div:first-child"))
    )
except:
    print "[-] No joy..."
user.send_keys("email@gmail.com")

# Target the password input field
user.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
user.send_keys("password")

# submit the login form
login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".rc-LoginForm > form > button")
login_button.click()

# Choose Intro to Data Science with Python course
course = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".rc-EnrollmentsList")
course.click()
```

This isn't working and tells me that the element cannot be located. I've tried many solutions, including checking that the document ready state equals "complete", switching to new windows, checking for the presence of an element, and checking if the title has changed. Nothing seems to work, and if I print the page source, it is in fact that page source from the initial window load, which is why I think none of the above methods worked.

How do I tell Selenium that I've switched to a new page and it needs to update its source of information?

Note: I know that Coursera has extremely stringent policies on web scraping and any and all materials are for non-commercial use only. The sole purpose of performing this task is to automate the downloading of videos for courses in which I have enrolled so I can view them later.

Comment: I am too experiencing the same problem, did you get a solution?

Answer (score -1):

This  seems  purely like a  wait issue. You have  to add some  wait  statements to the script.Though the website moves to the next  page the  script still stays on the  previous page- this happened to me too. Just add a
 "Thread.sleep(2000)
 before  you move to the next  page. if it works then add a  standard  wait  statement.Increase the seconds so that you can  find the issue. Note that, the more times you execute the same piece of code, the  time  it takes to load varies(mostly increases!)

So try  a  sleep statement and check if you are on the new  page, then you can standardize it later. Happy coding.